# Are regular grammars always LR(1)

Tags: context-free, parsers

The question is fairly straight forward. I just found a question on the internet that asks whether all regular grammars are

1. LL(1)
2. LR(1)

I guess they can't be LL(1) because of left recursion, but how do we prove that they are LR(1) if so.

Comment: First provide a definition of *regular grammar*.  E.g. according to http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/grammar/reg-grammar.html they cannot be left recursive.

Comment: I took it to mean the wikipedia definition for regular grammar, which could be both left recursive and right recursive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

Comment: I notice Wikipedia unexplainably lacks a definition of a LR(k) grammar. So you'll need to get that from a textbook and apply it.

Comment: @reinierpost That's far from unexplainable. The article has probably been mostly written by programmer-types. (There's a notable decline of rigor all over Wikipedia the farther along the road from mathematics to programming -- or even mathematical/formal topics programmers find relevant.)

Comment: There are plenty of people of people here who could fix it ...

Comment: @reinierpost True. As I've commented before, my experience with editing Wikipedia has been less than encouraging so I can't really recommend bothering. That said, I agree that it is good if someone bothers enough to go through the pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

LR(k) grammars have to be *unambiguous*, that is there can be only one possible parse tree for every (valid) input. There are left- and right-regular grammars violating that, for example

$\displaystyle\qquad S \to aS \mid aaS \mid a$

or, if that one does not match your definition of right-regular,

$\qquad\displaystyle\begin{align}
  S &\to aS, S \to aA, \\
  A &\to aA, A \to a
\end{align}$

as [reinierpost](/users/917) mentions in a comment.

Of course, every regular language *does* have an unambiguous (right-)regular grammar; get one from its minimal DFA using the standard construction.

Comment: Yes. Such grammars can still be ambiguous, e.g. $S \rightarrow aS, S \rightarrow aA, A \rightarrow aA, A \rightarrow a$.  They can't when they're simple (which is defined incorrectly in Wikipedia, I'll fix it).

Comment: @reinierpost Thanks, edited. I don't know what you mean by "simple" but one can certainly give a name to the class of all unambiguous regular grammars.

Comment: Simple = in Greibach Normal Form with all right hand sides for the same nonterminal starting with a different terminal. So it's very close to $\epsilon$-less LL(1).